# Inject Kotlin inline class with Dagger/Hilt

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Is there a way to inject instances of a Kotlin inline class with Dagger? In other words is there any way to get this code to compile assuming that we have a Dagger component that includes UserModule?

```
inline class Username(val name: String)

@Module
class UserModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUsername(): Username = Username("default_user")
}

class MyClass @Inject constructor(private val username: Username)
```

I am specifically trying to do this on Android using Hilt. Not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: Why dont you write `@Inject constructor ` in front of (val name: String), so:  `inline class Username @Inject constructor(val name: String) ` ??

Comment: That might work if every Username has the same value. But in the real code we need different values for the username in different classes. We need to be able to provide a Username with a provider function annotated with a @Qualifier annotation.

Comment: No. I don't think so. To my mind, you confound the concept of @Inject with @Singleton. When you write `@Inject constructor` is does not mean, that you always provide the same value. Writing `@Singleton class UserName @Inject constructor()` would mean to always provide the same value.

Comment: The point is that we need to be able to specify which Username is injected at the point of injection, by using an annotation. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I think Dagger is simply unable to inject Inline classes.

Comment: What error you are getting when trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Same here - wanted this instead of injecting a "Named" or class instance wrapper string via Hilt:

```
@JvmInline
value class ApplicationFlavor @Inject constructor(private val flavor: String) {
    fun isPaid() = flavor.equals("paid", true)
    fun isFree() = flavor.equals("free", true)
    fun trial() = flavor.equals("trail", true)
}
```

but decided to settle for using a class instance since I couldn't seem to find a workaround:

```
class ApplicationFlavor...

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideApplicationFlavor() = ApplicationFlavor(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that inline/value kotlin classes kind of not existing in Java. For Java they're just their values and all the type information is needed and usable only in kotlin itself.

If you will run "Show kotlin bytecode" action for your file in Android Studio and then click "Decompile" you will see that the type `provideUsername()` is returning and the type in the constructor of `MyClass` are both just `String`.

Part of decompiled `MyClass`:

```java
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 9, 0},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0012\b\u0007\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003ø\u0001\u0000¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0004R\u0019\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003X\u0082\u0004ø\u0001\u0000ø\u0001\u0001ø\u0001\u0002¢\u0006\u0004\n\u0002\u0010\u0005\u0082\u0002\u000f\n\u0002\b\u0019\n\u0005\b¡\u001e0\u0001\n\u0002\b!¨\u0006\u0006"},
   d2 = {"Lcom/genovich/MyClass;", "", "username", "Lcom/genovich/Username;", "(Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V", "Ljava/lang/String;", "Visual_IDE.app.main"}
)
public final class MyClass {
   private final String username;

   private MyClass(String username) {
      this.username = username;
   }
```

Part of decompiled `UserModule`:

```
@Module
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 9, 0},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000\u0014\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\u0018\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004H\u0007ø\u0001\u0000ø\u0001\u0001ø\u0001\u0002¢\u0006\u0004\b\u0005\u0010\u0006\u0082\u0002\u000f\n\u0002\b!\n\u0005\b¡\u001e0\u0001\n\u0002\b\u0019¨\u0006\u0007"},
   d2 = {"Lcom/genovich/UserModule;", "", "()V", "provideUsername", "Lcom/genovich/Username;", "provideUsername-YGuWp1o", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "Visual_IDE.app.main"}
)
public final class UserModule {
   @Provides
   @NotNull
   public final String provideUsername_YGuWp1o/* $FF was: provideUsername-YGuWp1o*/() {
      return Username.constructor-impl("default_user");
   }
}
```